# supported SQL function list inside sqlContext.sql("query"): having, match_recognize.etc

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am wondering if `sqlContext.sql("query")` will support all the SQL function used in ORACLE sql such as `having`, `match_recognize` used in CEP, other analytic combined with windows function?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

sqlContext.sql("query") will NOT support everything used in ORACLE sql. However it supports everything used in Hive including analytic funtions.